# Wordpress User Account in separate script

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I am in the process of building a website for someone. There are two sections of the site. A wordpress site with ecommerce and a third part script. I would like to link the logins so that the users login details are the same for both the wordpress site and the script. Any idea how I would go about this?

Comment: Well WordPress has a users table, can you just use that?

Comment: That is what I was thinking but the passwords are hashed?